# Using Bigquery regexp_extract to get column names

Tags: regex, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, metadata

I need a query using the *query* column in the view INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT to get the column names of queries that are being submitted using the string function *regexp_extract*.

With regard to aggregate functions, we can remove count(*) from consideration and alias names are not to be matched. I only want the column name without the parentheses and the function name (e.g. max, min). Also, it should be case insensitive and can match column names in any number of areas in the query.
The way I've been thinking about using regexp_extract is to get back all matches between SELECT and FROM and then processing that to remove any parentheses and aggregate function names, but I'm not sure how to turn this into a working BQ query.

In this example, I am looking to get back staff_id.

```
WITH cte_sales AS (
    SELECT 
        staff_id, 
        COUNT(*) order_count  
    FROM
        sales.orders
    WHERE 
        YEAR(order_date) = 2018
    GROUP BY
        staff_id

)
SELECT
    AVG(order_count) average_orders_by_staff
FROM 
    cte_sales;
```

Answer (score 1):

In perfect world this type of use cases should be addressed with use of [ZetaSQL](https://github.com/google/zetasql), see also [ZetaSQL Toolkit](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/zetasql-toolkit)

Meantime, if you really badly need to make it within the pure BigQuery - see below approach (check [ML.GENERATE_TEXT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-generate-text) for details)

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION get_column_names(text STRING) AS ((
SELECT TRIM(STRING(ml_generate_text_result['predictions'][0]['content']), '" ')
  FROM ML.GENERATE_TEXT(MODEL `your_project.your_dataset.your_model_llm`,
  (SELECT FORMAT("In provided SQL text - provide list of columns used in SELECT statements. SHow only columns from input data, ignore computed columns in output. Do not provide any comments, explanations. Don't even provide header to that list. Just show list of columns: %s", text)  AS prompt)
)));
WITH sample_data AS (
  SELECT '''WITH cte_sales AS (
      SELECT staff_id, COUNT(*) order_count  
      FROM sales.orders
      WHERE YEAR(order_date) = 2018
      GROUP BY staff_id
    )
    SELECT AVG(order_count) average_orders_by_staff
    FROM  cte_sales;''' AS sql UNION ALL
  SELECT '''SELECT id, ST_UNION_AGG(ST_POINTN(ring, index)) outer_points,
      ANY_VALUE(point) point, ANY_VALUE(points) points
    FROM your_table, 
    UNNEST([ST_EXTERIORRING(ST_BUFFER(point, 100e3, num_seg_quarter_circle => points /4))]) ring,
    UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, ST_NUMPOINTS(ring) - 1)) index
    GROUP BY id''' 
)
SELECT sql, get_column_names(sql) AS columns
FROM sample_data
```

with output

[image]